Unable to connect from MySQL Workbench to AWS RDS instance
I have created a MySQL instance in AWS and trying to connect with it from MySQL workbench from my local system.
I made the MySQL instance publically accessible, added a security group and set inbound rules to allow traffic. as shown below




But when I am trying to connect from MySQL workbench
I get error as shown here

I spent almost a day to resolve this but no luck
Anyone please help me.
Here is the route tables


subnets:

route table :


Can you please check the route table to ensure that Internet gateway is attached to the subnets associated with your RDS instance ?

How long does it take to fail -- does it give the error immediately (indicating authentication issues), or does it take 5-10 seconds to fail (indicating networking issues)? Was the database launched in a public subnet? Also, can you test that the domain name resolves to a public IP address (not starting with 10.) -- you can do this with ping xxx.rds.amazonaaws.com. The ping will probably fail, but it will show whether the domain name resolves to an IP address.

Hi @JohnRotenstein, it takes arount 10 seconds theg get error. Also the ping fails.

Hi @MANISH, I have edited my question and added route tables screenshot. please check

The database need to be in public subnet to be publicly accessible. The way a subnet can be made public is by attaching an Internet gateway. Can you check the route table RDS-pvt-rt (guess the one you are using) to see if Internet Gateway is attached or not?

It's okay that the ping fails, the important part was to see what IP address it returns. I can see that it starts with 18., which is a public IP address. This is good.

The first screenshot is showing that you configured the DB Subnet Group with five subnets. It is highly likely that this is a mixture of Public Subnets and Private Subnets, and that the database has launched in a private subnet. If you want the database to be accessible from the Internet, then the Subnet Group should only contain public subnets.

@JohnRotenstein, I have attached subnets screenshot, can you please guide me what should I do to attach public subnets to a subnet group?

@MANISH, route tablke  RDS-pvt-rt  is attached , please check.

I can see that all the five subnets were explicitly associated with the route table RDS-pvt-rt. Also there is no Internet gateway attached to the route table. That means all the five subnets are private. The database was launched in one of there five private subnets. Hence the database is not accessible from outside world. Attaching a Internet gateway to the Route table will make all the subnets Public, consequently will make the Database accessible from outside world.

I have added the details on how to make a subnet public in the Answer section. I am not sure about your use case, but it is always recommended as a best practice to keep databases in private subnet and access the database using a bastion host.

Looks like the database is launched in a private subnet. If the need to publicly access the data, it need to be in a public subnet. A subnet can be made public by attaching Internet Gateway to the route table associated with the subnet.
Please follow the steps below to attached Internet Gateway to the Route table.

Open the Route Table
Click on Edit Routes
Click on Add route
Select Destination as 0.0.0.0/0
Select Target as Internet Gateway
Save Changes


Wow!... This resolved my issue, now I am able to connect with AWS rds from my local MySQL workbench. You made my day!!! Thank you so much @MANISH
